# Find the median of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, median

I wrote some code that returns the median of an unsorted odd numbered array, but it does not return the median of an even numbered array.

I know that in order to find the median of an even numbered array, you have to take the middle two numbers of the array, average them, and that's the median. I can't translate that into usable code. Aside from the obvious verbosity of this code, the issue seems to be with lines 7-8 and I don't see why.

I prefer hints to answers, but if you rather post some fixed code, I can accept that too.

```
def media(array)
  sorted = array.sort
  list = sorted.length
  if list %2 != 0
    (list + 1) / 2.0
  else
    even = ((list.to_f + 2) / 2) + ((list.to_f / 2)
    return (even/2)
  end
end
```

Comment: jr, the need to do the operations on the elements of `sorted`, not on it's length.  Note that sorting doesn't do anything for you now; `list = array.length` would produce the same results.  You need to work with `sorted`.

Comment: For odd length, you're returning the median *index*. For even length, there is no index you can return, right? Therefore rewrite this so that it returns the calculated values instead. E.g. for an odd array, return `sorted[(list+1)/2]` and for an even array, return `(sorted[i]+sorted[i-1])/2` where you will need to calculate `i`.

Comment: Are you trying to find the median *value* in the array, or the *index* of the median in the sorted array? Because your code seems to be trying to do the latter.

Comment: Remember that ruby array indexing starts at zero, so the indices of interest are `array.length / 2` when the length is odd, or `array.length / 2` and `(array.length / 2) - 1` if the length is even.

Comment: Thanks these are helpful.  Getting stuck immediately again -- I do not know what's going on with the code in the second answer: 'sorted[(list+1)/2]' and '(sorted[i]+sorted[i-1])/2'.  Should that be read as "sorted times list + 1, divide that by 2" and "sorted times i + sorted times (i -1), then divide that by 2" ?

Comment: May be [this][1] link will be helpful.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451169/finding-median-for-even-length-array-in-ruby

Comment: ok thanks all -- i added the key word "value" in my google search on calculating array medians and the post that Emu linked to pops right up.

Comment: Should the input array remain unsorted, or is the method allowed to alter it by sorting it in-place? Your example created a sorted copy, but it's not clear if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to just jump in with a solution here...

```
def median(ary)
  mid = ary.length / 2
  sorted = ary.sort
  ary.length.odd? ? sorted[mid] : 0.5 * (sorted[mid] + sorted[mid - 1])
end
```

Edit - I've incorporated `.odd?` as per BroiSatse's suggestion.

Comment: Using `& 1` is really strange. Better would be `% 2 == 0` or `.odd?` as recommended by @BroiSatse.

Comment: @tadman I guess I'm showing my age. Back in the day we had it smacked into us to avoid division-based operations whenever possible, which includes `%`.

Comment: Perhaps change `? sorted[mid] :` to `? sorted[mid].to_f :` so that it always returns a float.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The median is one of the actual values when n is odd, but the average of two values when n is even. Returning a float in the second case is the right thing to do, but in the first case I think it's better to return the value as-is.

Comment: @pjs Here's some [simple benchmark results](https://gist.github.com/tadman/8741869) that show `% 2 == 0` and `& 1 == 0` are virtually identical in performance, and `even?` is moderately faster. Keep in mind I had to run *ten million* cycles to produce a measurable result, so the difference is extremely small. I think `even?` and `odd?` win in terms of performance and readability.

Comment: @tadman I believe you, as I said it's a matter of upbringing. Forty years ago division could make your program an order of magnitude slower than using bit-wise operations. Anyway, I agree on readability which is why I revised the answer.

Comment: pjs, suppose `median` were used to compute a float like this: `median(arr)/v`, where `v` is an integer.  Because we don't know if `median` will return an integer or a float, we need `median(arr)/v.to_f` instead.  Better to just have it always return a float.  For the same reason, `25**0.5 => 5.0`, not `=> 5`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I prefer to stick with the statistical definition, which says the median is one of two things, a raw value or an average of two values, depending on whether the cardinality of the set is even or odd.  If somebody wants to use the median for subsequent operations, it's up to them to ensure that they're using it in a manner consistent with the operation they want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

```
  a = [1,2,4,5,3,6]
  sorted = a.sort
  list = sorted.length
  if list %2 != 0
    puts sorted[list/2]
  else
    puts (sorted[list/2]+sorted[(list/2)-1])/2.0
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_median(values)
  quotient, remainder = values.sort!.length.divmod(2)
  medians = [values[quotient], values[quotient-(remainder+1) % 2]].uniq
  medians.length > 1 ? medians.map(&:to_f).reduce(:+) / 2 : medians[0]
end
```

This *should* work, but let me know if it does not.

*edit*  forgot to add .to_f to medians values.  Here is my testing in Pry.

```
[1] pry(main)> def get_median(values)
[1] pry(main)*   quotient, remainder = values.sort!.length.divmod(2)
[1] pry(main)*   medians = [values[quotient], values[quotient-(remainder+1) % 2]].uniq
[1] pry(main)*   medians.length > 1 ? medians.map { |v| v.to_f }.reduce(:+) / 2 : medians[0]
[1] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> values = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[3] pry(main)> get_median values
=> 2
[4] pry(main)> values << 4
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[5] pry(main)> get_median values
=> 2.5
[6] pry(main)> get_median values << -1
=> 2
[7] pry(main)> values
=> [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[8] pry(main)> values << 11
=> [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11]
[9] pry(main)> get_median values << -1
=> 2
[10] pry(main)> values
=> [-1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11]
[11] pry(main)> values.delete_if { |v| v == -1}
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 11]
[12] pry(main)> values << -1
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, -1]
[13] pry(main)> get_median values
=> 2.5
[14] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Try some simple test cases where you know what the answer ought to be.  `[11,10,12]` should yield 11; `[11,10]` should yield 10.5.

Comment: Corrected that and posted my testing in pry.  Learned my lesson about posting code without really testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
def get_median(sub_a)
    result = -1
    size = sub_a.size
    if size == 0
        result = 0
    elsif size == 1
        result = sub_a[0]
    elsif size == 2
        result = get_average(sub_a[0], sub_a[1])
    else
        sorted_a = sub_a.sort
        index = size / 2
        if size % 2 == 0
            result = get_average(sorted_a[index - 1], sorted_a[index]);
        else 
            result = sorted_a[index];
        end
    end

    '%0.01f' % result
end
```